# How to set colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in nativescript

Tags: android, statusbar, nativescript

before continuing i have to say that i've read a lot of questions about this and any solution didn't work for me.
I am working with nativescript(v2.1.1) and i'm trying to change the status bar and actionbar color using the xml files approach, but i couldn't make it work.
Here is my attempt:

path: app/App_Resources/Android/values/colors.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ns_primary">#3f51b5</color>
    <color name="ns_primaryDark">#2137aa</color>
    <color name="ns_accent">#3f51b5</color>
</resources>
```

path: app/App_Resources/Android/values/styles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
    </style>
</resources>
```

path: app/App_Resources/Android/values-v21/colors.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ns_primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="ns_primaryDark">#2137AA</color>
    <color name="ns_accent">#3F51B5</color>
</resources>
```

path: app/App_Resources/Android/values-v21/styles.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Does anyone know if i am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Setting them in the colors.xml in app_resources works.  Just make sure you create a new build of the app and run it. If you've ran/built the .apk before uninstall it from any emulator/device so the new build is installed and there are no caching issues.

Comment: If so could you accept the answer for others to find easier